# Websocket service always running

Tags: react-native, mobile, service, websocket, socket.io

I am starting with a new project for mobile app, and I plan to use ReactNative as my framework and Socket.IO as my websocket.
What I want to do with the socket is: my app needs to listen for new entrys in a database and, when it happens, a new notification is shown to the user.

So, I am considering using a service that is always running connected to my websocket. However, I am concerned that it might consume too many resources (e.g., battery and hardware) to be left running in the background continuously. Is this a reasonable solution? If not, what approach should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume that websockets (with or without socket.io) are still opened in the background. Therefore you should consider combining websockets (when the socket is opened, so app in foreground) with fcm (app is background).